# How can I select summation value of record columns that are different?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

**The following query isn't correct but I want something like that**

```
SELECT sum(price) AS price, sum(paid) AS paid
FROM finance
WHERE sum(price) != sum(paid)
GROUP BY item_id
```

What I want is to retrieve the total **price** and **paid** of an item that has been sold but not fully paid yet.

(which mean the total price and total paid are different)

**Edit 1**

This is my table structure

```
// table schedule_member
schedule_member_id (PK)
schedule_id (FK: schedule.schedule_id)
student_id (FK: student.student_id)
fee
paid
added (Current timestamp)
```

the sql query was

```
SELECT sum(fee) AS total_fee, sum(paid) AS total_paid 
FROM schedule_member 
WHERE total_fee != total_paid 
GROUP BY student_id
```

then then error came up, **#1054 - Unknown column 'abc' in 'where clause'**

Comment: Could you describe the `finance` table please?

Comment: There is no column named `price` and that's why it's erroring

Comment: see my edit; as per your table structure

Answer (score 3):

Try using `HAVING` in place of `WHERE`

```
SELECT sum(price) AS pricesum, sum(paid) AS paidsum
FROM finance
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING pricesum <> paidsum
```

Answer (score 2):

How about like this

```
SELECT sum(fee) AS totalfee, 
sum(paid) AS totalpaid 
FROM finance 
WHERE totalfee < totalpaid 
GROUP BY item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(price) AS price, sum(paid) AS paid
FROM finance
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING sum(price) != sum(paid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just looking for the following?

```
SELECT sum(price) AS total_price, sum(paid) AS total_paid
FROM finance
WHERE price <> paid
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: @Martijn, I think you mean `WHERE total_price <> total_paid`

Comment: not yet fixed, you have aliased the sum() as different name but in WHERE clause using the actual column name

Comment: @Tar_W45, see my last comment.

Comment: It's not working anyways. I'm editing the first post to show you my table.